# Inline methods of two dependant structures?

Tags: c++, include, inline

I want to inline my two structures. But they have pointer of each other. Like the code below:

**A.h**

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

#include "b.h"

struct A
{
    B* b;
    int value;

    A();
    void Inc();
};

#endif // A_H
```

**A.cpp**

```
#include "a.h"

A::A()
{
    b = new B(this);
}

void A::Inc()
{
    b->value++;
}
```

**B.h**

```
#ifndef B_H
#define B_H

struct A;

struct B
{    
    A* a;
    int value;

    B(A* a);
    void Inc();
};

#endif // B_H
```

**B.cpp**

```
#include "b.h"
#include "a.h"

B::B(A *a)
{
    this->a = a;
}

void B::Inc()
{
    a->value++;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <a.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.value = 0;
    a.b->value = 0;
    a.Inc();
    a.b->Inc();
    cout << a.value << endl;
    cout << a.b->value << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I can not use keyword `inline` anywhere because it gives me the error `undefined reference to methods`.

Based on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769479/c-inlining-class-methods-causes-undefined-reference), I can define my methods in header files but that would force me to use `#include <a.h>` inside the file `b.h`. But that would give me another error because of duplicate includes.

Now How can I inline both Inc methods?

Comment: Just don't try. `inline` is in fact more of a linkage specification nowadays than an actual in-lining hint for the compiler. If you build both source files into one object, I assure you that your compiler is more than smart enough to inline what's needed (and even do optimizations you or I can't think of).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to inline all member functions of two mutually dependent `struct`s in the body of the `struct` definition. It's possible to inline all the member functions by defining the functions outside the body of the `struct` definition and using the `inline` keyword explicitly. However, if you use two .h files to define the `struct/class`s, it becomes messy.

Here are some options to implement the member functions.

**Option 1**

Use only forward declarations in the .h files. Implement all the functions in the .cpp files. None of the member functions are inlined.

**Option 2**

Use forward declaration of `A` in `B.h` but use full definition of `B` in `A`.
In this case, all member functions of `A` can be inlined but member functions of `B` cannot be inlined. They will need to be implemented in a .cpp file.

**Option 3**

Reverse the roles of `A` and `B` from **Option 2**

Use forward declaration of `B` in `A.h` but use full definition of `A` in `B`.
In this case, all member functions of `B` can be inlined but member functions of `A` cannot be inlined. They will need to be implemented in a .cpp file.

Comment: "It's not possible to inline all member functions of two mutually dependent structs." Really? Yes it's not possible to inline them *inside the declaration body* (the place where the method were declared), but nothing stops you to 'inline' them outside, separately, after the full declaration of both structs are fully know. From the perspective of the resulted object files, there's no difference between the two (inline in decl-body or outside it).

Answer (score 0):

`a.h` and `b.h` stay the same, `a.cpp` and `b.cpp` are merged into `ab_inl.hpp` containing the methods and constructors with an `inline` decorator****** (or you can let the constructors be in their respective `.cpp` file) and the `main.cpp` (or any other file which needs it) includes `ab_inl.hpp`.

---

<sub>****** as the compiler is free to ignore the `inline` qualifier, I preferred the term "decorator"</sub>

---

Everything below + `a.h` + `b.h` compiles just dandy:

File `ab_inl.hpp`:

```
#ifndef _AB_INL
#define _AB_INL

#include "a.h"

// included by a.h anyway
// #include "b.h"

inline A::A() : b(0), value(0)
{
    b = new B(this);
}

inline void A::Inc()
{
    b->value++;
}

inline B::B(A *a) : a(0), value(0)
{
    this->a = a;
}

inline void B::Inc()
{
    a->value++;
}

#endif // _AB_INL
```

File `main.cpp`

```
#include "ab_inl.hpp"


int main()
{
    using std::cout;
    using std::endl;

    A a;
    a.value = 0;
    a.b->value = 0;
    a.Inc();
    a.b->Inc();
    cout << a.value << endl;
    cout << a.b->value << endl;
    return 0;
}
```