# g++ cannot link my class function if I define it in a separate file

Tags: c++, linker

I am trying to write a simple program in C++ and I get a linker error that has been driving me crazy for the past 3 days. I have managed to get it down to a minimal (non) working example.

So I have in the same folder 3 files: `main.cpp`, `ComGameTypes.h` and `ComGameTypes.cpp`.

The contents are:

`main.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ComGameTypes.h"

int main() 
{
    GameState gs;
    gs.get(1);
    return 0;
};
```

`ComGameTypes.h`:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

class GameState 
{
    public:
    std::array<int, 27> data;

    int get(int);
    GameState();
};
```

`ComGameTypes.cpp`:

```
#include "ComGameTypes.h"

inline int GameState::get(int i) 
{
    return data[i];
};

GameState::GameState() 
{
    std::cout << "Gamestate constructor running\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < 27; i++)
    {
        data[i] = 0;
    }
};
```

When I try to compile by `g++ .\main.cpp .\ComGameTypes.cpp -o a` this I get a linker error that there is an `undefined reference to 'GameState::get(int)'`.

The kicker is that if I add the line `#include "ComGameTypes.cpp"` in `main.cpp` and run `g++ .\main.cpp -o a` it compiles without errors! What causes this?

Comment: It is the inline keyword... it will look for one with external linkage and not find it...

Comment: @GradyPlayer oh! How do I define this properly? Do I need to define it as inline in the header file?

Comment: Hi, the inline function should be defined in the header https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769479/c-inlining-class-methods-causes-undefined-reference

Comment: Remove `inline`.

Comment: OMG, I spent so many hours on that! Thank you all!

Comment: Older information about [inline](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/033.htm), may still have relevance, but not 100% sure.